# Blogger Old Post not showing on landing page

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views, microblogging

I have a blog from blogger and one of my issues is my very first blog post is showing on a seperate page when you hit the landing page.

www.westworldtheories.com

Any new posts I make work fine and show on the landing page but the old one does not show, you have to click -> next, on the landing page to see the old post. It also does not show the image for the old post.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a setting to choose how many posts display per page? Look into the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the settings for the number of posts displayed on home page by going into `Blogger dashboard` > `Settings` >  `Posts, comments and sharing settings` > `Posts` > `Show at most`

[image: Settings to change post per page]